# Full property of a hom functor over vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

My question is regarding the property of fullness for the below functor over vector spaces. This example comes from [Leinster - Example 1.2.12, p23](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf).

Let $k$ be a field. For any two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over $k$,
there is a vector space
$\mathbf{Hom}(V,W) = \{ \text{linear maps } V \rightarrow W\}.$
The elements of this vector space are themselves maps, and the vector space
operations (addition and scalar multiplication) are defined pointwise.

Now fix a vector space $W$. Any linear map $f: V  \rightarrow V ′$ induces a linear map
$f^*: \mathbf{Hom}(V ′,W) \rightarrow \mathbf{Hom}(V,W)$,
defined at $q \in \mathbf{Hom}(V ′,W)$ by taking $f^*(q)$ to be the composite map
$ V \overset{f}\rightarrow V^\prime \overset{q}\rightarrow W$.

This defines a functor
$\mathbf{Hom}(−,W) : \mathbf{Vect}^{op}_k \rightarrow \mathbf{Vect}$.

I am stuck trying to prove/disprove fullness. My instinct is it is full for finite dimensional vector spaces, so I suppose I should start with this assumption first. However I can't see how to recover any property of $f$, given a morphism $f^*$ on two objects in the destination category.

Comment: If $W = 0$, then $\hom(-,0)$ is the constant zero functor. For non-trivial examples you could maybe start  with $W = k$. In that case, the functor $\hom(-,k)$ can be identified naturally with the functor $V \mapsto V^\ast$.

Comment: Thanks @qualcuno! I didn't need to specialise W, any tips on where I have gone wrong? Seems to be quite definitional to me. In our source category we have the linear map $f\colon V \rightarrow V^\prime$. $f$ induces a linear map in the destination category $q\colon V^\prime \rightarrow W$. Equivalently this map can be rewritten as acting on $V$ as $q \circ f$. Observing this relation, every morphism in the destination category must have a preimage morphism in $V$, as by definition $q$ composes $f$. So the functor is full.

Comment: As you speak of dimensions: If dim$(W)=m$ and dim$(V)=n$ then dim(Hom$(V,W))=nm$. The dimension of Hom(Hom$(V,W)$, Hom$(V',W)$) is $m^2nn'$. But the dimension of $\{f^*: f:V' \to V\}$ is at most $nn'$. If thus $m\ge 2$, the functor Hom$(-,W)$ is not full.

Comment: Thanks @Jochen, this is essentially the answer. It would be good if the UI allowed users to promote comments to accepted answers.